# CKEditor Remove (selected) from label on click

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I have created a simple plugin to move some of the formatting buttons to a dropdown button. The dropdown button has both an icon and a label. The plugin works as intended except that when clicked on the label shows both the intended text as well as adding "(selected)" to the end.

Here is the button default view (the formatting button):

[image]

And here is how it looks when clicked on:

[image]

Here is the code for the plugin:

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'sf_formatting', {
init: function( editor ) {
     var format = {};
        editor.addMenuGroup( 'format_group' );


        format.indent = {
            label: 'Increase Indent',
            group: 'format_group',
            command: 'indent',
            order: 6
        };

        format.outdent = {
            label: 'Decrease Indent',
            group: 'format_group',
            command: 'outdent',
            order: 7
        };



        editor.addMenuItems( format );

        editor.ui.add( 'Formatting', CKEDITOR.UI_MENUBUTTON, {
            label: 'Formatting',
            // Disable in source mode.
            modes: { 
                wysiwyg: 1 
            },
            icon: 'dropdown',
            onMenu: function() {
                var active = {};

                // Make all items active.
                for ( var p in format )
                    active[ p ] = CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_OFF;
                    return active;
                }
            } ); 
        }
});
```

**I have a second issue**

The outdent (decrease indent) only appears when the text has been indented. In the main menu it is always there but greyed out. How can I force the outdent button to always be visible in the dropdown box but not accessible.

Here is a screenshot of the dropdown when the text has been indented:

[image]

I'd be really grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to create a hack to make this work as no one seems to know the answer.

In the language file, the relevant entry is "%s (Selected)". %s is replaced by the menu title in the plugin code.

I just removed the "(Selected") and now it works fine FOR MY USE.

It may break other things I am unaware of, but it works for me